# How to understand Shamos algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, convex-hull

I wanted to find shortest time algorithm for finding the diameter of a convex hull, so I found Shamos algorithm on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers#cite_note-preparata1985-4):

```
GetAllAntiPodalPairs(p[1..n])
    i0 = n
    i = 1
    j = i + 1
    while (Area(i, i + 1, j + 1) > Area(i, i + 1, j))
        j = j + 1
        j0 = j
    while (j != i0)
        i = i + 1
        yield i, j
        while (Area(i, i + 1, j + 1) > Area(i, i + 1, j)
            j = j + 1
            if ((i, j) != (j0, i0))
                yield i, j
            else 
                return
        if (Area(j, i + 1, j + 1) = Area(i, i + 1, j))
            if ((i, j) != (j0, i0))
                yield i, j + 1
            else 
                yield i + 1, j
```

And this is a gif to visualize the algorithm:

[image: calipers]

I cannot understand the **Area** in the code . how it will be calculated given i , i+1 and j+1?
And what's exactly the p[1..n] ? Is it the given points or that's different?

I've created a shape for solving that using this algorithm. I know that's not easy but can someone trace the algorithm for this shape? Anybody like me will enjoy it:
[image]

Comment: Is the bottom middle point of your example supposed to be (2, 0) rather than (2, 4)?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick research, this is what I understand from the code and the wiki page:

- P is the array of vertex of the convex hull, sorted in clockwise (or counter-clockwise).
- Area(i,j,k) calculates the area of the triangle formed by P[i],P[j], and P[k]

The code is trying to find parallel lines showing in the gif.

the code block

```
while (Area(i, i + 1, j + 1) > Area(i, i + 1, j))
        j = j + 1
        j0 = j
```

is trying to find the farest point **j0** relative to the Line **L** formed by P[i],P[i+1].
A line parallel to **L** and pass the point **j0** and the line **L** itself forms a line pair in the gif.